# Trouble with Pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

First time posting. I am very new to pivot tables and have looked up several answers on how to create them, but I cant seem to get mine to work. Is a pivot table the correct way to go?

What I'm trying to do is take all the columns and make them rows and the rows become the columns. Basically turn the table 90 degrees. See Image.

Thanks

[Image of Base query results and results I'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7xLj.png)

Base query

```
SELECT        dbo.EstimateDetails.EstimateDetailID,
          dbo.EstimateDetails.QtyOrdered,
          dbo.EstimateDetails.NetPrice, 
          dbo.EstimateDetails.ExtendedPrice, 
          dbo.EstimateDetails.EstimateID, 
          dbo.UserDefined_Custom.UserDefined1, 
          dbo.UserDefined_Custom.UserDefined2,
          dbo.EstimateDetails.OrdUOMID, 
          dbo.Estimate.EstimateNo, 
          dbo.EstimateDetails.[LineNo] AS Line

FROM            dbo.EstimateDetails 
                INNER JOIN dbo.Estimate 
                ON dbo.EstimateDetails.EstimateID = dbo.Estimate.EstimateID 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UserDefined_Custom 
                ON dbo.EstimateDetails.ItemSpecID = dbo.UserDefined_Custom.ItemSpecID
                where dbo.EstimateDetails.EstimateID = 141865
```

Where I'm at now with no luck.

[Results with Pivot attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQAcB.png)

```
Select 
Pvt.[1], Pvt.[2], Pvt.[3], Pvt.[4],Pvt.[5],Pvt.[6] 
from

(SELECT        dbo.EstimateDetails.EstimateDetailID,
              dbo.EstimateDetails.QtyOrdered,
              dbo.EstimateDetails.NetPrice, 
              dbo.EstimateDetails.ExtendedPrice, 
              dbo.EstimateDetails.EstimateID, 
              dbo.UserDefined_Custom.UserDefined1, 
              dbo.UserDefined_Custom.UserDefined2,
              dbo.EstimateDetails.OrdUOMID, 
              dbo.Estimate.EstimateNo, 
              dbo.EstimateDetails.[LineNo] AS Line

FROM            dbo.EstimateDetails 
                INNER JOIN dbo.Estimate 
                ON dbo.EstimateDetails.EstimateID = dbo.Estimate.EstimateID 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UserDefined_Custom 
                ON dbo.EstimateDetails.ItemSpecID = dbo.UserDefined_Custom.ItemSpecID
                where dbo.EstimateDetails.EstimateID = 141865
) AS Src

PIVOT
(
    Max(EstimateDetailID)
    for Line in ([1], [2], [3], [4],[5],[6])

) AS Pvt
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Comment: Yes, I am using MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need a full transpose, so first **unpivot** then **pivot**. Note that you need to convert all columns to a common type.

I personally tend to prefer using `CROSS APPLY` instead of `UNPIVOT`, I find it much clearer.

You should also use aliases for tables, it makes the query much easier to write and read.

```sql
Select 
    Pvt.Col AS Line, Pvt.[1], Pvt.[2], Pvt.[3], Pvt.[4],Pvt.[5],Pvt.[6] 
from (
    SELECT
        ed.[LineNo] AS Line,
        Upvt.Col,
        Upvt.value
    FROM dbo.EstimateDetails AS ed
    INNER JOIN dbo.Estimate AS e
      ON ed.EstimateID = e.EstimateID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UserDefined_Custom AS udc
      ON ed.ItemSpecID = udc.ItemSpecID
    CROSS APPLY (
        ('EstimateDetailID', CAST(ed.EstimateDetailID AS varchar(50)),
        ('QtyOrdered',       CAST(ed.QtyOrdered AS varchar(50)),
        ('NetPrice',         CAST(ed.NetPrice AS varchar(50)), 
        ('ExtendedPrice',    CAST(ed.ExtendedPrice AS varchar(50)), 
        ('EstimateID',       CAST(ed.EstimateID AS varchar(50)), 
        ('UserDefined1',     CAST(udc.UserDefined1 AS varchar(50)), 
        ('UserDefined2',     CAST(udc.UserDefined2 AS varchar(50)),
        ('OrdUOMID',         CAST(ed.OrdUOMID AS varchar(50)), 
        ('EstimateNo',       CAST(e.EstimateNo AS varchar(50)) 
    ) AS Upvt(Col, Value)
    where ed.EstimateID = 141865
) AS Src

PIVOT
(
    Max(Value)
    for Line in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
) AS Pvt
```

---

To be honest, looking at it now, I realize you really are just transposing it for display, so the column names don't really make sense (`Line` has the columna names in it for example). I'd advise you to do this in a client application, T-SQL is really not the place for this.